# PHP failed to download uploaded file from database since uploaded with chinese filename

Tags: php, mysql, database, file-upload, download

Excuse me, I am building a web site that can let user upload their document(pdf) to the mysql database.

Since I have wrote the upload and download php page, I could upload files(pdf) and download english named files successfully, but fail to download the files whose name contain chinese words.

More specifically, I can download the chinese named file, but couldn't open it. It shows that the file is damaged.

Here is a part of code of my upload php page:

```
        $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "table");
        if(mysqli_connect_errno($connect))//check connection
        {
               /*show error message and die*/
        }
        //set client character set to 'utf8'
        mysqli_set_charset($connect, "utf8");

        $fileName = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $name);
        $filePath = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $tmp_name);
        $fileSize = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $size);
        $fileType = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $type);
        $content = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, file_get_contents($tmp_name));

        $filePath = addslashes($filePath);

        if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        {
            $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
        }

        $teamName = $_COOKIE['teamName'];
        $reportQuery = "UPDATE uploadedreport SET name='$fileName', type='$fileType', size='$fileSize', content='$content' WHERE team='$teamName'";



        uploadFileQuery($connect, $reportQuery, $fileName);
        mysqli_close($connect);
```

Besides, another part of code of download php page is:

```
    $teamName = $_COOKIE['teamName'];
    $downloadReportQuery = "SELECT name, type, size, content FROM uploadedreport WHERE team='$teamName'";


    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $downloadReportQuery);
    if($result == false)
    {
      /*alert error message and die*/
    }

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    header("Content-length:$row[size]");
    header("Content-type:$row[type]");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$row[name]");//Tells the browser to save this downloaded file under the specified name

    echo $row["content"];
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_close($connect);
```

It's there anything wrong?
I am disturbed by this problem for several days.

Thanks for your help!

Using Notepad++ to open the damaged downloaded pdf file:
[little part of downloaded pdf](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4gn9Ui-e0KgZjZuZUtjNUxNMHc/edit?usp=sharing)

There is my html code of upload page:

```
<div id="pageDiv">
    <section id="mainSection">
        <div id="mainDiv">
            <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <table id="mainTable">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="headColumn paragraphTitle"><label for="uploadedReport">競賽報告上傳</label></td>
                            <td><span class="hint"><span id="reportDueText"></span>截止</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><div id="uploadedReportDiv"><input id="uploadedReport" name="uploadedReport" type="file" required /></div></td>
                            <td><span class="hint">請以pdf格式上傳</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="headColumn paragraphTitle"><label for="uploadedBriefing">競賽簡報上傳</label></td>
                            <td><span class="hint"><span id="briefingDueText"></span>截止</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><div id="uploadedBriefingDiv"><input id="uploadedBriefing" name="uploadedBriefing" type="file" required /></div></td>
                            <td><span class="hint">請以ppt, pptx 或pdf格式上傳</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr><td colspan="2"><input id="uploadButton" type="submit" value=""/></td></tr>
                        <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="headColumn paragraphTitle">檢視已上傳檔案</td>
                            <td><a id="downloadUploadedFile" href="#">未上傳</a></td><!-- link to download file. If user has uploaded it, href will be changed by the javascript function afterUploaded -->
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

The other side, this is my javascript code of upload page:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        setDateText(reportDue, "reportDueText");
        setDateText(briefingDue, "briefingDueText");

        afterUploaded();

        if(now > reportDue)
        {
            $("#uploadedReportDiv").hide();
            $("#uploadedReport").attr("required", false);
        }

        if(now > briefingDue || now <= reportDue)
        {
            $("#uploadedBriefingDiv").hide();
            $("#uploadedBriefing").attr("required", false);
        }

        $("form").submit(
            function()
            {
                var validateReport = false;
                var validateBriefing = false;

                if($("#uploadedReportDiv").is(":visible") && $("#uploadedReport").val().length > 0)
                {
                    validateReport = validateUploadedFile($("#uploadedReport").val(), "pdf");
                }
                else if(!$("#uploadedReportDiv").is(":visible"))
                    validateReport = true;

                if($("#uploadedBriefingDiv").is(":visible") && $("#uploadedBriefing").val().length > 0)
                    validateBriefing = validateUploadedFile($("#uploadedBriefing").val(), "pdf ppt pptx");
                else if(!$("#uploadedBriefingDiv").is(":visible"))
                    validateBriefing = true;


                if(!validateReport)
                    alert("檔案格式錯誤，請上傳pdf格式檔案。");//alert upload wrong file format
                if(!validateBriefing)
                    alert("檔案格式錯誤，請上傳ppt, pptx 或pdf格式檔案。");//alert upload wrong file format

                return (validateReport && validateBriefing);
            }
        );
    }
);

function setDateText(date, objectId)
{
    var dateText = (date.getFullYear()-1911) + "/" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "/" + (date.getDate());
    $("#" + objectId).text(dateText);
}

function validateUploadedFile(filename, validExtensions)
{
    var splitedArray = filename.split(".");
    var fileExtension = splitedArray[splitedArray.length-1];

    if(validExtensions.indexOf(fileExtension) == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

function afterUploaded()
{
    if($.cookie("isUploaded"))
    {
        $("#downloadUploadedFile").attr("href", "download.php").text("下載檔案(" + $.cookie("uploadedFileName") + ")");
    }
}
</script>
```

Thank you!

Comment: What does the downloaded PDF file contain? Can you look at it using a plaintext or hex editor?

Comment: Can you open the downloaded file if you first change the name to be something else, say: test.pdf

Comment: @AntoanMilkov If I changed the name of download file when downloading, using Content-Disposition header, the file is still damaged.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I have opened the downloaded pdf file, using text editor, Notepad++, and grabbed a little part of the content from the beginning of the document to show. Could you tell me how can I find out where the error is?

Comment: @JTofu What is happening if you save the file at the server before sending it? Do a fast md5sum and see if the local content is the same as the remote content.

Comment: Where does the HTML code in the file come from? That's most likely the culprit

Comment: @AntoanMilkov I use php md5() function to get the md5 hash of the content before uploading to database and downloading from database. They are not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your answers it is clear that the file is not the same after you read it from the DB, so clearly something is wrong there.

It is true that MySQL supports binary data types. Just because you can, however, does not imply that you should. MySQL sends results to a client all at once. Consequently, any application parsing a result set with binary data needs to wait for each row to arrive before it can be processed. Furthermore, there is no real benefit to storing the binary data in MySQL.

A better approach to binary data is to store that data on the file system and store pointers to those files in MySQL. With this approach, you can actually stream the binary data in background threads while you process the result set.

This tip does not apply only to binary data; it applies to any kind of large data objects. The performance issues that plague binary data also plague character data. In other words, the reading of any part of a result set is done serially. You will take more notice with binary data since it is usually large. You will notice the problems equally with large character data. You do need to weigh the performance benefits of storing large character data on the file system against the ability to search against that data in the database.

However if you insist on storing files into the DB, then be sure to use **BLOB** type field  for it.
See the relevant [manual page here.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html)

Answer (score 0):

Probably, storing the binary file data in a database is not a good idea. It would be better if you move the uploaded file to some directory with the help of move_uploaded_file() PHP function, and put only the file name to the database.

Comment: Yes, I have heard that way would be better, but I want to fixed the problem that I have. Could you give me more advice? Thanks.